# How to connect multiple BLE devices through android application?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, rxandroidble, bluetooth-gatt

I am working on android and BLE device connectivity. I want to connect multiple BLE devices on same time . How to achieve this ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/overview this might help

Comment: This is a bit vague question. One device needs to be a peripheral (advertiser) and another needs to be a client that can connect to the peripheral. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can connect to more than one BLE device from your android application.

CONNECTING: Call this code for each BLE device `mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);` Save all the  `mBluetoothGatt` in to list.

READING: In `mGattCallback` methods `onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)` or `onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status)` has `gatt` parameter. `gatt.getDevice().getAddress()` will give you the mac address of the BLE device from where you've received the data.

WRITING: Using `mBluetoothGatt.getDevice().getAddress()` you always know the device you are pointing to. You can write the command to it. In `mGattCallback` method `onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status)`, parameter `gatt` will give you the mac address to confirm the write command.

You can have single `mGattCallback` for all your connections. If you what to differentiate and don't want to always compare mac addresses, go for single callback for each connection.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36055034/3044529) will tell you how many connections can your android device can support.

Feel free to ask if you still have doubts.

Comment: okay, i will try this.. thanks. I will message you if i found any difficulty.

Comment: @j.prashant This is very similar to single ble communication. If you really need an example, give me couple of days. I'll host it on github.