# How to check my devices support connected maximum Bluetooth in code?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Refer [Android: Limit of simultaneous BLE connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400182/android-limit-of-simultaneous-ble-connections)).
Can We get maximum Bluetooth connected in code?

Answer (score 1):

No there is currently no method for getting the maximum connected devices in the code. However, please assume that the maximum is 7 as this is the default value in the Android source code. Please see this:-

- [GATT_MAX_PHY_CHANNEL](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/master/include/bt_target.h#1428)

Also here are some relevant answers:-

- [What is the max concurrent Ble connections android M+ can have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365009/what-is-the-max-concurrent-ble-connections-android-m-can-have/41367864)
- [How many devices we can pair via Bluetooth of BLE to Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154919/how-many-devices-we-can-pair-via-bluetooth-of-ble-to-android)

As can be seen from answers above, this value can be changed by the hardware vendor to increase or decrease the number of connections a device can have, so this can change from one hardware vendor to another, but unfortunately there is no Android API to return this value in the code.

I hope this helps.