# Need my app to connect to two BLE devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection, bluetooth-lowenergy

I know it's been discussed on here before, but i never found a concrete demonstration on how this is achieved. So far I'm able to connect to one device, and this is what i have so far:

A MainActivity with no layout

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Handler mHandler;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mHandler = new Handler();

    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }

    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("E8:FF:34:49:A9:5B");
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceControlActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
    intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS, device.getAddress());
    startActivity(intent);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // User chose not to enable Bluetooth.
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        finish();
        return;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Ensures Bluetooth is enabled on the device.  If Bluetooth is not currently enabled,
    // fire an intent to display a dialog asking the user to grant permission to enable it.
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enable Bluetooth in phone settings.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

DeviceControlActivity with code to manage Service lifecycle.

```
private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new           ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
        mBluetoothLeService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service).getService();

        if (!mBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");
            finish();
        }
        // Automatically connects to the device upon successful start-up initialization.
        mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        mBluetoothLeService = null;
    }
};
```

Establish connection in onCreate

```
Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BluetoothLeService.class);
    bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Receiver to handle various events fired by the Service.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            mConnected = true;
            updateConnectionState(R.string.connected);
            mConnectionState.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF17AA00"));
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            mConnected = false;
            updateConnectionState(R.string.disconnected);
            mConnectionState.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            //clearUI();
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            // Show all the supported services and characteristics on the user interface.
            //displayGattServices(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());
            List<BluetoothGattService> servs = mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices();
            for (int i = 0; servs.size() > i; i++) {

                List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> charac = servs.get(i).getCharacteristics();
                for (int j = 0; charac.size() > i; i++) {
                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch = charac.get(i);
                    if (ch.getUuid() == chara) {
                        mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(ch);
                        mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(ch, true);


                    }
                }
            }

        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
            displayData(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA));
        }
    }
};
```

After some research, i'm under the impression that i would have to edit the BluetoothGattCallback to be able to manage 2 connections. What i have so far:

```
  private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        String intentAction;
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
            // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
            Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                    mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
            Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
            gatt.readCharacteristic(services.get(2).getCharacteristics().get
                    (0));
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(final BluetoothGatt gatt,final
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
                    gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
                }
            }).start();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you see this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237093/android-4-3-how-to-connect-to-multiple-bluetooth-low-energy-devices

Comment: Thank You for responding, and yes i did. But the most detailed solution involves using a queue, and i would to avoid that.

Comment: The problem is, from my understanding, without creating a queue you can't be certain that the devices wouldn't be overriding one another.

Comment: Where exactly would the queue be implemented ?

Comment: looks like i would have to rewrite the service

Comment: nvmd, i figured it out.