# About HM-10 BLE with multiple device communication

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10

I'm doing a project that need some BLE communication.
For now, I have two device in my project, A and B, A they all using HM-10 BLE module and A is in slave mode B will be in master mode.

When active, A B will connected and transfer data. I also want to have my iphone connect to B, is this possible? Like two master connect? Since I see a master in bluetooth can have connection up to like 6 or 7 device.

I have read the datasheet and did many search on google but didn't find any answer.

Can someone help me with that or where should I go for help or learn? Thanks.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237093/android-4-3-how-to-connect-to-multiple-bluetooth-low-energy-devices

Comment: You will need your iOS app to act as a  BLE peripheral via CBPeripheralManager. You need to check if a HM-10 can connect to multiple peripherals simultaneously when acting as a central, which I doubt it can